# Android Studio 1.2: Error:Android Source Generator: [app] AndroidManifest.xml file not found

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest, manifest, updates

I updated to AS 1.2 and I just tried importing/opening one my previous projects that worked on the previous version of AS. However, when I try building the project, I get an error saying

```
Error:Android Source Generator: [app] AndroidManifest.xml file not found
```

but this doesnt make sense since my manifest is src/main folder. How can I fix this and avoid this problem for all of my other projects?

Answer (score 1):

This also bothered me recently, and I'm guessing that Gradle wasn't building it right.

In my circumstance, I just hit the ***Sync Project with Gradle Files*** button at left of ***AVD Manager*** button. If possible, you can goes with Gradle command lines as well.

then it popped out some errors said that I failed to find Build Tools revision 21.0.2(also this had been installed again and again, assuming I didn't set it right).

After installed some SDKs, clicked finish, studio will automatically rebuild your project.

There it works, can run the project now.